# How to import sbt projects to Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, sbt, sbteclipse

I want to import my sbt projects to Eclipse. While searching on the Internet I came to know there is an sbteclipse plugin for Eclipse to import sbt projects, but I don't know how to do this.

I am using Eclipse Kelper and sbt 0.13 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr** Use [Scala IDE for Eclipse](http://scala-ide.org/).

[sbteclipse](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse) is a plugin for sbt itself and aims to *"create Eclipse project definitions"* that in turn doesn't require installing *any* plugins in Eclipse.

sbt is a build tool while Eclipse is an IDE. While both use the concept of *plugins* these plugins have nothing in common (unless you're at higher architecture level where almost all converges).

Comment: when i import project into eclipse and create class files it did not appear in the original directory i mean the in project folder there is no class appear which i create in eclipse any suggestions?

Comment: I don't use Scala IDE so won't help in this case. Ask another question under [tag:scala-ide] tag.