# How to import BOTH Git repository and Maven dependencies to Eclipse?

Tags: java, git, eclipse, maven, github

I am trying to run [this tool](https://github.com/clulab/reach).

It says that the jar is available on Maven. I created a Maven project in Eclipse and added dependencies in pom.xml. At the same time, I cloned the git repository to Eclipse, but then I have 2 separate projects: one is the Maven project with dependencies and another is cloned git.
Is it possible to combine them? Are there any other ways to install and run a project from github with Maven dependencies?

I checked similar questions but they resolve either Maven or GitHub importing which I know how to do. I am having problems with doing both in one eclipse project.

Thank you.

UPD: I want to inspect Reach tool to see if it fits my research purposes

Comment: Do you just want to use the `reach` library in your own project - like you would use any other library in any other JAR? If so, just use the Maven import - and there is no need to clone the git repo. If you want to inspect - and maybe also make changes to - the `reach` source code, or perhaps step through the `reach` source code when you are debugging your own code, then clone the git repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [README](https://github.com/clulab/reach/tree/554640f44157da96e1f88f5fa5629e7e0a7e3290#installation) it's a standard SBT project, so if you want to import it in Eclipse IDE I would advise to use the [Scala IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25372919/10226142) (Eclipse plug-in) and [sbtclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25996681/10226142) (plug-in for SBT).

That being said, the Scala IDE is not maintained anymore so it may be easier to use [SBT support in IntelliJ](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.6.x/java/IntellijSbtJava.html) instead.

Anyway you have to clone the git repository locally. From Eclipse IDE you can import it afterwards, see [sbtclipse's README](https://github.com/sbt/sbteclipse#installation-and-basic-usage).